# What's the difference of the Akka's Actor with Scala's Actor model

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I found there is also an Akka actor model, so I am wondering what's the difference between the Akka's Actor and Scala's Actor model?

Comment: See [What's the difference between the different Actors implementation in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5997018/53013)

Comment: Scala actors are now deprecated in favour of Akka actors, so why bother? :) http://goo.gl/VaPOu

Comment: Starting `Scala 2.10`, `scala.actors` library became deprecated in favor of Akka actors.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well, there isn't. There is just Actor model, and Akka actors and Scala actors are two *implementations* of that model.

All Actor model says that your concurrency primitives are actors, which can:

- receive a message and decide what to do next depending on the content of the message, including:
- send messages to any actors they know about
- create new actors

and provides certain guarantees, e.g.:

- any actor will only handle a single message at a time
- messages sent by actor X to actor Y will arrive in the order thay were sent

There is no difference between Scala and Akka actors on this level.

For differences in what they can do, see [Different Scala Actor Implementations Overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906162/different-scala-actor-implementations-overview). The biggest one, for me, is that Akka supports supervisors and ActorRegistry.

Comment: The comparison PDF linked to by the accepted answer seems to be no longer available. Here's a comparison from one of the Akka developers: http://akka.io/docs/misc/Comparison_between_4_actor_frameworks.pdf

Comment: Your link is 404 too. This is currently working: http://doc.akka.io/docs/misc/Comparison_between_4_actor_frameworks.pdf

Answer (score 33):

There is also a historical answer. The creators of Scala thought there should be an actor framework. Jonas Bonér tried it out, but was not completely satisfied so he started working on a new - which evolved into Akka. However, the Scala people thought it was better than their own - so at Jfokus 2011 they announced that Akka was to become the standard actor framework of Scala. However, that migration will take some time.

Comment: Yup, Scala Actors library is already deprecated in 2.11 http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 9):

This depends a little on what you mean with "model" - you can either refer to the "execution model" or the "programming model" (and perhaps other models as well).

For execution models, there are basically two: thread-based or event-based. The Scala standard actor library contains both. The thread-based uses one thread for each actor, whereas the event-based uses a thread-pool. The former is more intuitive to understand, the latter is more efficient. Akka is built on the event-based model.

For programming model, there is a big difference between the scala standard library and Akka. In the scala standard library, you basically implement the "run" method - and if you want to wait for an incoming message, you get yourself into a waiting state (by calling "receive" or "react"). So, the programming model follow the "thread-metaphor". However, in Akka, the programming metaphor is that you implement a few life-cycle methods - but the "run"-method is written inside the framework. It actually turns out that this programming model works a lot better with the event-based execution model as well.

If you are interested in the different execution models and programming models of scala standard actors I have written [a](http://dearjunior.blogspot.se/2011/05/scala-actor-waiting-for-godot-vladimir.html) [few](http://dearjunior.blogspot.se/2011/05/vladimir-galore-lots-of-threaded-scala.html) [posts](http://dearjunior.blogspot.se/2011/05/how-heavy-is-estragon-event-based-scala.html) on the issue.